# QGIS Print layout not showing detail on export

Tags: qgis, export, printing, save

When I save a map the output is missing a lot of the detail you can see in the print preview. Why is this and is there a way I can save it like I see it in the preview? Saves well as a pdf but not as a png. I need it in png format rather than pdf. Exporting as pdf than converting to pdf isn't successful either.

##### This is the saved output:

[image]

##### This is what it looks like in the Preview:

[image]

##### These are my symbology settings (all polygons):

[image]

##### These are my export settings:

[image]

Comment: Please provide export settings, as well as relevant layer types and symbology settings.

Comment: Have you tried creating and exporting a layout? Does it behave different?

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/index.html

Comment: Have you tried different export formats?

Comment: I've tried PDF which works, but I need it in a png/jpeg format. As png doesnt work. I've tried converting the pdf to png but seems to produce a similar output.

Comment: Is the DPI the same in your preview ? `Layout Properties >Export Settings > Export Resolution`?  than in your export ?

Comment: @Kasper yes both 300dpi

Comment: Do you get better results at 900 dpi for instance ? Can you share your polygon layer ?